# Why 'in' used in "shaking the bag of pastilles in his face"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

> "I insist!" said Hermione aggressively, **shaking the bag of pastilles in his face**. Looking rather alarmed, the little wizard took one.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I don't understand why 'in' should be used in that phrase, rather than 'in front of' or 'on'? What does it mean?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in-your-face

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an idiom, not to be taken literally. "To be in X's face" means to be "too close for X's comfort."

Comment: Getting "in someone's face" isn't just an invasion of someone's personal space, like standing too close; it is confronting them in a way that's impossible to ignore. https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+your+face